# Limit the text displayed in the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown button. I want to limit the text display in the button after I select an item in the dropdown, so the button doesn't expand. (ex. Some Kids..., instead of Some Kids In The School) Kinda like a max-width, but setting max-width doesn't seem to work. I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cmb1ctw9/1) but can't seem to get it to work with the dropdown items. Same with the embedded code below

```js
$('#clientGroups li').on('click', function () {
            $('#spnSelectedGroup').text($(this).text());
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group ">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="btnClientGroups" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span id="spnSelectedGroup">Groups</span>  <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul id="clientGroups" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: The dropdown isn't working because you've reference bootstrap.min.js before jQuery. Swap them over and then the dropdown will work.

Answer (score 1):

By using CSS you can set a fixed width on the inner text and add ellipsis with `text-overflow: ellipsis`

```
#btnClientGroups > span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#spnSelectedGroup {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umhs3hc1/)